# BindingSource.Find key comparison is case insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm using BindingSource.Find() to return to the user's position after refreshing a DataGridView.  I use BindingSource.Find() and a RowID as the DataColumn I'm searching on.  Unfortunately, Oracle can return two RowIDs that differ only in their case.

BindingSource.Find() returns the first match regardless of case.

Looking at the MSDN docs:

```
public int Find(string propertyName, Object key)
```

it says that the propertyName comparison is case-insensitive, but does not mention whether the key comparison is.

Does anyone know how to make BindingSource.Find case sensitive?

Comment: I still haven't been able to find a solution for this one.  Following the docs a little further: for a DataView (which I believe is my underlying list) it says this calls IBindingList.Find.  There is no word about whether this is case sensitive or not, but there is a example of creating a class that has custom searching.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.find.aspx

I expect I should be able to use this example to create a custom search for DataView that is not case sensitive, but, I don't know where to begin.

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `DataView` all you should need to do is set the `CaseSensitive` property of the parent `DataTable` to true. I just quickly prototyped that with the following code and it works fine:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataSet set1 = new DataSet();

    // Some xml data to populate the DataSet with.
    string testXml =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
    "<numbers>" +
    "<number><name>one</name></number>" +
    "<number><name>two</name></number>" +
    "<number><name>Two</name></number>" +
    "<number><name>three</name></number>" +
    "</numbers>";

    // Read the xml.
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(testXml);
    set1.ReadXml(reader);

    // Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset.
    DataTableCollection tables = set1.Tables;
    // Set the CaseSensetive property
    tables[0].CaseSensitive = true;
    DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

    // Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.            
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;            

    // Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
    // the DataView.
    BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
    source1.DataSource = view1;

    // Set the data source for the DataGridView.
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;

    // Set the Position property to the results of the Find method.
    int itemFound = source1.Find("name", "Two");
    source1.Position = itemFound;
}
```

For other types of IBindingList you need, as the docs say, an underlying list that implements a Find which is case sensitive. For completeness I have shown the code to do this below:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // This uses my CaseSensitiveBindingList which I have code for later
    BindingList<DGVItems> source = new CaseSensitiveBindingList<DGVItems>() 
        { 
            new DGVItems { Number = "one" },
            new DGVItems{Number = "two"},
            new DGVItems{Number = "Two"}
        };

    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource.DataSource = source;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

    var index = bindingSource.Find("Number", "Two");

    // Index is 2 (third item) as desired.
    MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());

}

public class DGVItems
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for the CaseSensitiveBindingList is:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, object key)
    {
        string stringKey = key as string;            

        bool keyIsString = stringKey != null;

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        {
            if (keyIsString && prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
            {
                if (stringKey.Equals(prop.GetValue(Items[i]).ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                    return i;
            }
            else
            {
                if (key.Equals(prop.GetValue(Items[i])))
                    return i;    
            }

        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

That code could almost certainly be improved but shows the general concept.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the complete examples.  I haven't tried them yet, but they looks solid.